# how to select columns from another dataframe , where these columns are list of value of column in different dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql 2.3.1v with java8.
I have data frame like below

```
 val df_data = Seq(
  ("G1","I1","col1_r1", "col2_r1","col3_r1"),
  ("G1","I2","col1_r2", "col2_r2","col3_r3")
 ).toDF("group","industry_id","col1","col2","col3")
.withColumn("group", $"group".cast(StringType))
.withColumn("industry_id", $"industry_id".cast(StringType))
.withColumn("col1", $"col1".cast(StringType))
.withColumn("col2", $"col2".cast(StringType))
.withColumn("col3", $"col3".cast(StringType))

+-----+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|group|industry_id|   col1|   col2|   col3|
+-----+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|   G1|         I1|col1_r1|col2_r1|col3_r1|
|   G1|         I2|col1_r2|col2_r2|col3_r3|
+-----+-----------+-------+-------+-------+


val df_cols = Seq(
  ("1", "usa", Seq("col1","col2","col3")),
  ("2", "ind", Seq("col1","col2"))
 ).toDF("id","name","list_of_colums")
.withColumn("id", $"id".cast(IntegerType))
.withColumn("name", $"name".cast(StringType))


+---+----+------------------+
| id|name|    list_of_colums|
+---+----+------------------+
|  1| usa|[col1, col2, col3]|
|  2| ind|      [col1, col2]|
+---+----+------------------+
```

Question :
   As shown above I have columns information in "df_cols" dataframe.
   And all the data in the "df_data" dataframe.
   how can I select columns dynamically from "df_data" to the given id of "df_cols" ??

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you edit your question and add the output dataframe you expect in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Initial question:

```
val columns = df_cols
  .where("id = 2")
  .select("list_of_colums")
  .rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]).collect()(0)

val df_data_result = df_data.select(columns(0), columns.tail: _*)

+-------+-------+
|   col1|   col2|
+-------+-------+
|col1_r1|col2_r1|
|col1_r2|col2_r2|
+-------+-------+
```

Updated question:

1) We may just use 2 lists: static columns + dynamic ones

2) I think that "rdd" is ok in this code. I don't know how to update to "Dataframe" only, unfortunately.

```
val staticColumns = Seq[String]("group", "industry_id")
val dynamicColumns = df_cols
  .where("id = 2")
  .select("list_of_colums")
  .rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]).collect()(0)

val columns: Seq[String] = staticColumns ++ dynamicColumns
val df_data_result = df_data.select(columns(0), columns.tail: _*)

+-----+-----------+-------+-------+
|group|industry_id|   col1|   col2|
+-----+-----------+-------+-------+
|   G1|         I1|col1_r1|col2_r1|
|   G1|         I2|col1_r2|col2_r2|
+-----+-----------+-------+-------+
```